# URLConnection execute in Spring bean return code 403

Tags: program-entry-point, http-status-code-403, spring-bean

I develop a Java class which contain a method open a URL connection to RESTFUL and get data. If I run it as Java application (main function), it run good, server return code 200 OK with data returned. But when I try to call that method in another spring bean @service, it return 403 error. Same code, same class but different way to call and different http code return.

Is there anyone see it before? Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks all.

UPDATE: my code

```
public static String call(String urlStr, String USER_AGENT, String TRUSTED_THIRDPARTY, String PRIVATE_HASH) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

    String headerString = "";

    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*,*");
    headerString += "accept: *,*\n";
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    headerString += "user-agent: " + USER_AGENT + "\n";
    connection.setRequestProperty("X-Trusted-Third-Party", TRUSTED_THIRDPARTY);
    headerString += "x-trusted-third-party: " + TRUSTED_THIRDPARTY + "\n";

    String message = urlStr + ":" + headerString + ":";
    String hash = base64sha256(message, PRIVATE_HASH);

    connection.setRequestProperty("X-hash-authen", hash);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String decodedString = "";
    while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(decodedString);
    }
    in.close();

    return decodedString;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant portions of the code from your application and Spring bean?  Please include the URL you are trying to access.

Comment: Hi Tim, it's a private code so that I can not post it. I can describe that all request header such as User-agent, accept... is full. The url is like http://<host>/api. I mean very thing is formal and nothing special on my case but result return is different when you run in main function and calling in spring-bean.

Comment: Are you calling `localhost` or something else?

Comment: yes, I call from localhost not try in another yet

Comment: So are both calls to `localhost`?  Your last comment is unclear.

Comment: Yes, both is call in localhost.

Comment: One last question: Are you using `HttpsURLConnection`?

Comment: First time I use UrlConnection, after that I try HttpURLConnection. HttpsURLConnection i haven't try yet. All can not work when call in spring bean in tomcat

Comment: I would strongly advise you to post your code, even if you have to disguise or obfuscate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87350/discussion-between-quan-m-le-and-tim-biegeleisen).